# JVM bind error when adding Ratpack to spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, ratpack

I have existing spring boot application. I want to enable ratpack support in the spring boot application. I am adding ratpack springboot depenendency and @EnableRatpack annotation and then starting the application. I am getting following exception. How to resolve this exception? Added picture of process 5620 - I am supposing netty started all these processes. [image]

Dependency

```
def ratpackVersion = '1.5.0'
compile "io.ratpack:ratpack-spring-boot-starter:$ratpackVersion"
```

Exception

```
[DEBUG] io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId - -Dio.netty.processId: 5620 (auto-detected)
[DEBUG] io.netty.util.NetUtil - -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack: false
[DEBUG] io.netty.util.NetUtil - -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses: false
[DEBUG] io.netty.util.NetUtil - Loopback interface: lo (Software Loopback Interface 1, 127.0.0.1)
[DEBUG] io.netty.util.NetUtil - \proc\sys\net\core\somaxconn: 200 (non-existent)
[DEBUG] io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId - -Dio.netty.machineId: 34:e6:d7:ff:fe:48:02:42 (auto-detected)
[DEBUG] io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil - -Dio.netty.allocator.type: pooled
[DEBUG] io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil - -Dio.netty.threadLocalDirectBufferSize: 65536
[DEBUG] io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil - -Dio.netty.maxThreadLocalCharBufferSize: 16384
[ERROR] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:803)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:784)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:771)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at com.agenabio.Application.main(Application.java:65)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:128)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:554)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1258)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:501)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:486)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your port on which your application is running is taken by some other application. Most probably it is because of Skype if you are using. You can do two things,
if in application.properties or application.yml

```
server.port=8080
```

then change it to some other random port , or stop your skype application if it is working on 8080 port